# Why does Vampire: The Masquerade have clans that are made or supposed to be unplayable?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, metaplot

If you play a Sabbat chronicle set in 2017, you can't play Tremere *antitribu*, because they don't exist anymore: "can't play" means "all Storytellers I asked would disallow such a thing due to Metaplot". You can't either play Salubri, except probably for Salubri *antitribu* if you are Sabbat-aligned. A Camarilla chronicle, even if you play Gangrel, would leave you with various social disadvantages, e.g. you don't have a Primogen. Ravnos were almost annihilated, some still exist, but no more than 2 can be in one coterie/pack, as they frenzy when they see each other.

Not even mentioning countless bloodlines, most of them not available for standard PCs for some reason.

However, I don't see any real benefit in that. What problems do Tremere in Sabbat and Gangrel in Camarilla cause? Why does the Metaplot render many options banned?

Comment: [A related question about Metaplots in RPGs](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97021/why-do-rpgs-have-metaplots)

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not discussion. Please take any discussion to [Role-playing Games Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=rpg.stackexchange.com). Prior discussion has been removed from question and answer post comments.

Comment: Do we really need a metaplot tag for this question and the linked one? Especially as they're both pretty much opinion pieces.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Which question are you asking? The title or one of the two in the last paragraph? Could you please fix this up so it's less of a rant and more of a serious question.

Answer (score 17):

I can't speak to ST decisions,  as every ST is allowed to determine for themselves what would and wouldn't work for their own game. That's entirely their prerogative.

STs aside, given Vampire's **20th Anniversary Edition**, and to a lesser extent By Night Studios' **Mind's Eye Theatre: Vampire The Masquerade**, there's nothing stopping you from playing any of the above options. V20 lets you play a Tremere *antitribu*, and both MET:VTM and V20's **Rites of the Blood** throw in options for having the Telyavelic Tremere (originally from the Dark Ages) as a new *antitribu* to replace the old ones.

You can certainly play Salubri in both V20 and MET:VTM, and V20's upcoming **Lore of the Bloodlines** has a whole chapter dedicated to them. Every bloodline is presented as playable in both versions of Vampire, although MET:VTM makes them slightly harder to get, requiring the investment of Merit points, IIRC.

Individual Gangrel can still be in the Cam. You're right that they may have disadvantages like not having Primogen representation, but that varies per city with virtually every clan anyway, and it's not like the Gangrel don't already have social disadvantages to contend with.

Ravnos frenzying with each other was in effect for a brief period following the Week of Nightmares in 1999 and has long since subsided.

It sounds like your question is less about what the game allows and more about why the STs in your area are restrictive on character options.

Answer (score 12):

During the original span of its publication, the World of Darkness operated on something like a periodical model, wherein the regular release of supplements to an audience at least as interested in reading about the affairs of its setting as playing through games of its own would fund new and upcoming projects. Changes to the setting via metaplot helped contribute to the feel of an evolving or changing world, as "real" as the one outside the window.

Thus, the social restrictions on playing such variants as Tremere *antitribu*, Kiasyd, Healer Salubri, Ahrimanes and so on impart the feeling that such anomalies are "rare" in the World of Darkness, and in doing so, give the impression that all World of Darkness campaigns take place in the same continuity — that the game you're in is somehow connected to the other games taking place. It's to foster a sense of camaraderie among players of the game.

This is, naturally, a false impression — if every single game being had one Salubri PC, that wouldn't make them any less rare any more than if every pre-show-end game of **Buffy the Vampire Slayer RPG** had a Slayer in it.

Comment: That last paragraph doesn't make much sense as not everyone has played that game, maybe substitute something different?

Answer (score 5):

The World of Darkness metaplot has always served the furthering of *a* story, not necessary *your* story (or that of your Storyteller), so the Storyteller should use creative license to adapt the metaplot as needed to further their own goals. The more important aspect of this process to be consistent and have the effects follow organically from the changes made.

For example of how the metaplot can be changed, in my modern game:

1. Baba Yaga still controls Russia with an iron fist.
2. [Tremere] cleansed the House of Goratrix.
3. Enoch still exists in the Shadowlands and is still under the control of the Tal’Mahe’Ra.
4. [Ravnos] was stopped before the Ravnos fell on themselves.
5. The Eye of Hazimel never surfaced, so Xavier and the Gangrel did not leave the Camarilla.
6. Vitel (as a known Lasombra) controls an independent Baltimore.
7. The Technocracy unilaterally controls Washington, D.C. and is probing New York City.
8. A power cabal of Vampires, True Fey, Garou, Fera, and Tradition mages has taken control of the Middle East.
9. [Tzimisce] has recently been diablerized.
10. Harold Zettler and his childe Persephone Tar-Anis have met Final Death.
11. Pentex will probably fall, then be bought by Shinzui Enterprise.
12. The Salubri will absorb the Tremere and the Furies.
13. The Sabbat will likely succumb to another civil war in the near future.
14. The Camarilla, having no obvious enemy, will probably fracture.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply put, because there are stories where having that information, for STs or players, may be important. Just because it is rare and unlikely to be of use to you, doesn't mean it has no use. For example a story that starts in the 1820s with players being turned could have any of the above involved in the story. Having their information, could help. And what if your storyteller wants to play through the fall of the Tremere Antitribu? There may even be a player with the stones to actually play on and try to live, knowing that it is highly unlikely.

Just because you cannot foresee a use for it, doesn't mean it's useless. Leave that description for the quality of your imagination.